# Connecting Turntable to Mic input to bypass preamp?

Tags: preamp

Would it be possible to connect a turntable to a mic input to completely bypass the preamp?

Comment: Which preamp are you hoping to bypass? A "mic" input generally has a preamp, just like a "phono" input does.

Comment: I do not have a phono preamp, but my PreSonus recorder has two XLR mic inputs.  Coudld I use two RCA to XLR cables from my turntable to my recorder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Won't work.

The output from a turntable is about 47k ohms. You need to get it to about 600 ohms for a standard line. Your mic is about 150 ohms (well, these can vary heavily though).

You need a [RIAA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIAA_equalization) pre-amp just to get to mic-input so might as well go for line.

Comment: The RIAA curve is critical for turntables. Even if you managed to impedance match with the mic pres, the lack of a RIAA curve would result in low quality sound.

Answer (score -4):

The connection of the turntable through the MIC input if it works, I have mine connected by that means and it does not need an external preamplifier. All is ok!

Comment: It will sound like cr@p though. The RIAA pre-amp isn't only to match impedances.